# How to pass an std::map with "any" enum to a function

Tags: c++

I have many enum declarations like

```
typedef enum {
    E_FOO_1,
    E_FOO_RANDOM,
    E_FOO_25,
} E_FOO;


typedef enum {
    E_BAR_RANDOM,
    E_BAR_SOMETHING,
    E_BAR_WHATEVER,
} E_BAR;
```

and I need a mapping to strings

```
std::map<E_FOO, const char*> fooMap = {
    {E_FOO_1, "completly different string"},
    {E_FOO_RANDOM, "hi"},
    {E_FOO_25, "down"},
};
std::map<E_BAR, const char*> barMap = {
    {E_BAR_RANDOM, "1234"},
    {E_BAR_SOMETHING, "3},
    {E_BAR_WHATEVER, "45"},
};
```

Is there anyway to write a function which takes something like `(uint8_t someEnumValue, std::map<any, const char*>)` and simply returns the string?

In the real application the structure is much more complicated and the `enums` are handled by some C-code, which has no problem to handle the enum values as `int` or `uint8_t` but I am not very used to C++, so I see no way to pass these parameters to a general function.

Could it be done by using templates? And wouldn't that blow up the compiled code since for every `enum` the function needs to be compiled (the function would be in a bigger class, so I would need to template the whole class).

Thanks!

Comment: C++ is not C.  They are different languages.  I removed the C tag.

Comment: I don't understand what your last paragraph is about... You can have templated functions in a non-templated class.

Comment: If you make them a proper `enum class`, you won't even need to pass the map itself to the lookup function.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Like I said, I am not (anymore) very used to C++ and the template stuff is the most complicated in my eyes. So, I simply did not know that.

@SamVarshavchik How would that look like? But I have no idea what would happen here, because there is a lot of C-code which uses the ```enums``` and rewritting all to C++ is no option atm.

@AndrewHenle I agree. I initialy added the tag because the ```enums``` are from the C-code part of the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *function template* to accept any `std::map` whose value type is `const char*`:

```
template <typename Enum>
const char* get_string(std::uint8_t v, const std::map<Enum, const char*>& m)
{
    return m.at(static_cast<Enum>(v));
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/m7ac03)

Comment: Not very important but I think `#include <cstdint>` and `#include <string>` preprocessor directives are missing in your live example to make it compile.

Comment: and should be `std::uint8_t`

Comment: and document that this can throw

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the lack of `noexcept` is that documentation. :P